# How to limit user's input to a range of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm beginner in python and I want to limits user entry between two numbers. How can I do that?

I want to set 0.2 for minimum and 100 for max and show a price of order.

Comment: What do you mean "user entry"? from command line? in a form ?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I want to write a simple code which gets a number (How much cheese do you want?) and show the price. Order amount has limits. How can I set that?

Comment: def CP(Cheese_Order):
    Cheese_Order = input("Enter Cheese Order Weight:").isdigit
    max(Cheese_Order)
    if (Cheese_Order>100):
        return(print(Cheese_Order, "is more than currently available stock"))
    elif (Cheese_Order<0.1):
        return(print(Cheese_Order, "is below minimum order amount"))
    elif (Cheese_Order<100 & Cheese_Order<0.1):
        return(print(Cheese_Order, "is below minimum order amount"))
    
CP

Comment: @ahmadrezarafati please edit your question, do not post your code in the comments.

Comment: The error is with the isdigit method. First you need to call `isdigit`, so you need to add `()` after the method. Second `isdigit()` returns a boolean. So somewhere in your code you need to put `if Cheese_Order.isdigit():`

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number between 0.2 and 100: ")
    if user_input.isdigit() and 0.2 <= float(user_input) <= 100:
        break
    else: 
        print("insert a number within the defined bounds!")
```

this approach can be modified to fit your specific needs. at first, you define a `while`-loop, which will be executed until you get a number from the user inside the bounds. then, you cast the user_input to `float`. Then, you `break` if it inside the limit, if it is not, the loop starts again from the beginning.

regarding your question in the comment...

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number between 0.2 and 100: ")
    if user_input.isdigit(): 
        if float(user_input) <= 0.2:
            print("below range")            
        elif float(user_input) >= 100:
            print("above range")
        else: 
            print("your're inside the range. well done")
            break
```

Comment: Judging from the code OP posted in the comments, the error he made was in using the isdigit method. `if user_input.isdigit() and float(user_input) >= 0.2 and float(user_input <= 100:` would make a better answer.

Comment: This can easily be crashed if the user enters a string for example

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to blow up the code with another 4 lines just for `try...` and `except ValueError:...` - but I will incorporate it into my answer!

Comment: If I want to show 3 different messages for below, middle and above range, what should i do?

Comment: btw, if it helped you solve your problem, you can accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure that the user cannot crash the program by giving bad input.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number between 0.2 and 100: ")
    if not user_input.isdigit():
        print("Bad input!")
    elif float(user_input) < 0.02:
        print("Input too small.")
    elif float(user_input) > 100:
        print("Input too large.")
    else:
        break  # input was fine, can exit the loop

# Use user_input here
```

Comment: If I want to show 3 different messages for below, middle and above range, what should i do?

Comment: @ahmadrezarafati edited my answer to show that. P.S. feel free to mark it as accepted if you feel that it answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

To limit an input range (assuming this is what you want) you can use a simple while loop such as:

```
userinput = float(input("How much cheese do you want? Enter a number between 0.2 and 100: "))

while ((userinput < 0.2) or (userinput > 100)):
    userinput = float(input("Value out of bounds. Enter a number between 0.2 and 100: "))

price = userinput * 0.05

print("This much cheese will cost", price)
```

I made the price $0.05 per gram, but you can set it at whatever you like.